# Rails theming ONLY "new" posts in a blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, content-management-system, themes

Common solutions found focused on creating themes or different CSS files for different pages or controllers.

Is there a solution wherby whenever I create a new blog post, I can as well select a theme from a dropdown, or the form_fields in the new_post page changes style and shape and layout based on selection of a theme, like from a sidebar?

Is there any gem like that, or how can we roll something related?

Comment: I'm not sure about the extent of your question, but a simple CSS class could change the entire look of the post, something like `<body class="themeA">` , where `"themeA"` is stored in the blog post. Are you looking for something more complex?

Answer (score 1):

Add a column in your database for "theme" and create a CSS file for each `Post` theme. In your view set the CSS of your `Post` container using the value stored in the database.

#### theme-1.css

```
.theme-1 {
  /* Some CSS */
}

.theme-1 p {
  /* Some CSS */
}

...
```

#### theme-2.css

```
.theme-2 {
  /* Some CSS */
}

.theme-2 p {
  /* Some CSS */
}

...
```

#### posts/show.html.erb

```
<div '#post-container' class='<%= @post.theme %>' %>
  ...
</div>
```

#### posts/show.html

```
<div '#post-container' class='theme-1' %>
  ...
</div>
```